# How to get the full graph plotted by R?

Tags: r

I've tried many times but still can't get the full image plotted by R, instead of a truncated one duo to "insufficient space"?

Please someone help me how to solve this problem.

below are my screenshot and R codes:

[image]

```
library(foreign, pos=4)
REmodeldata_continuous <- 
read.dta("F:/data for R.dta",
convert.dates=TRUE, convert.factors=TRUE, missing.type=TRUE, 
convert.underscore=TRUE, warn.missing.labels=TRUE)

library(R2WinBUGS)

REmodel_continuous<-function(){

for(i in 1:ns){                      #   LOOP THROUGH STUDIES  
w[i,1] <-  0    # adjustment for multi-arm trials is zero for control arm  
delta[i,1] < -  0             # treatment effect is zero for control arm  
mu[i] ~ dnorm(0,.0001)           # vague priors for all trial baselines 
for (k in 1:na[i]) {             #  LOOP THROUGH ARMS  
    var[i,k] < -  pow(se[i,k],2)   # calculate variances  
    prec[i,k] <-  1/var[i,k]      # set precisions 
    y[i,k] ~ dnorm(theta[i,k],prec[i,k]) # binomial likelihood 
    theta[i,k] < - mu[i] + delta[i,k]  # model for linear predictor 
#Deviance contribution 
    dev[i,k] < -  (y[i,k] -theta[i,k])*(y[i,k] -theta[i,k])*prec[i,k]  
   } 
#  summed residual deviance contribution for this trial  
resdev[i] < -  sum(dev[i,1:na[i]])         
for (k in 2:na[i]) {             # LOOP THROUGH ARMS  
# trial-specific LOR distributions 
    delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(md[i,k],taud[i,k])  
# mean of LOR distributions, with m ulti-arm trial correction 
    md[i,k] <-   d[t[i,k]] -  d[t[i,1]] + sw[i,k]  
# precision of LOR distributions (with multi-arm trial correction) 
    taud[i,k] < - tau *2*(k -1)/k  
# adjustment, multi-arm RCTs 
    w[i,k] <-  (delta[i,k] -  d[t[i,k]] + d[ t[i,1]])  
# cumulative adjustment for multi-arm trials 
    sw[i,k] < -  sum(w[i,1:k -1])/(k-1)  
   } 
}    
totresdev < -  sum(resdev[])            #Total Residual Deviance  
d[1]<-0       # treatment effect is zero for control arm  
# vague priors for  treatment effects  
for (k in 2:nt){  d[k] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) }  
sd ~ dunif(0,5)     # vague prior for between -trial SD 
tau <-  pow(sd,-2)   # between-trial precision = (1/between -trial variance)  

# All pairwise comparisons  
for (c in 1:(nt -1)) {  for (k in (c+1):nt)  { diff[c,k] < -  (d[c] -  d[k] )}}  
for (k in 1:nt) { 
rk[k] < -  nt+1 -rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “good”  
#rk[k] <-  rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “bad”  
best[k] < -  equals(rk[k],1) #calculate probability that treat k is best  
}         
}
# End of model

filename <- file.path("D://","REmodel_continuous.bug")

## write model file:
write.model(REmodel_continuous, filename)
## and let’s take a look:
file.show(filename)

#load data from dataset

t1<-REmodeldata_continuous$t1
y1<-REmodeldata_continuous$y1
se1<-REmodeldata_continuous$se1

t2<-REmodeldata_continuous$t2
y2<-REmodeldata_continuous$y2
se2<-REmodeldata_continuous$se2

t3<-REmodeldata_continuous$t3
y3<-REmodeldata_continuous$y3
se3<-REmodeldata_continuous$se3

t4<-REmodeldata_continuous$t4
y4<-REmodeldata_continuous$y4
se4<-REmodeldata_continuous$se4

na<-REmodeldata_continuous$na

t<-c(t1,t2,t3,t4)
y<-c(y1,y2,y3,y4)
se<-c(se1,se2,se3,se4)

dim(t)<-c(35,4)
dim(y)<-c(35,4)
dim(se)<-c(35,4)
ns<-35
nt<-23
data<-list("t","y","se","na","ns","nt")

#Set Initial Values
inits<-function(){ 
#Initial Values 
#chain 1  
list(d=c( NA, 0,0,0,0,0,0), sd=1, mu=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0,  
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  
0, 0, 0))

#chain 2  
list(d=c( NA,  -1, -3, -1,1,3,-1), sd=4, mu=c(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3,     -3, -3, -3,  
-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3,  
-3, -3, -3))

#chain 3  
list(d=c( NA, 2,2,2,2,2,2), sd=2, mu=c( -3, 5, -1, -3, 7,  -3, -4, -3, 5, -1,  
-3, 5, -1, -3, 7, -3, -4, -3, 5, -1,  
-3, 5, -1))
}

REmodel_continuous.sim<-    bugs(data,inits,model.file="D:/REmodel_continuous.bug",
                  parameters=c("diff","totresdev"),
                  n.chains=3,n.iter=40000,n.burnin=10000,
                  bugs.directory="C:/Program Files (x86)/WinBUGS14")

print(REmodel_continuous.sim, digits.summary=4)

plot(REmodel_continuous.sim)
```

Comment: If I'm right, the array is shown as the output of the plot() function. The help file ?plot.bugs doesn't give any argument that might override the automatic truncation. If you want to see the simulation array, you'll have to extract that one from the bugs object `REmodel_continuous.sim`. I believe this is a list, so `REmodel_continuous.sim$sims.array` should give you the array you're looking for.

Comment: PS: please look into vectorization, because right now you're using R in the most inefficient way. R is not C!

Comment: Thans for your comments!Yes, I've already got the results, but I still can't get the full graph, should I choose another way to plot it?

Comment: looks like it. If you check the source code of `plot.bugs` and `bugs.plot.summary` , you'll see that it's not possible to plot the full graph without writing your own plotting function. I find the programming logic also quite fuzzy and not easy to comprehend.